# Require.js, r.js and Rails

Tags: requirejs, ruby-on-rails-4, r.js

I am using Require.js in a rails 4 application.  However in the production environment I'd like to compile into 1 file and use almond.  Now obviously require.js recommends r.js, which even has a coffeescript plugin for it, but would mean running it outside of rails manually.

There is the requirejs-rails gem, but this seems to have not been updated for a while and doesn't have rails4 support.  There is a couple of forked version but I get an error when I try to use them:

```
`user_config=': undefined method `delete' for false:FalseClass **strong text**
```

I also not sure about using forked repos on a production app, particularly when I need to patch them to make it work.

So my question is how are other people managing AMD in rails4 app?  Anyone have any recommendations on best practice?  Is it easier writing my own script to manage production deployment and compiling the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
gem 'requirejs-rails', git: 'git://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails.git'
```

Instead of `gem 'requirejs-rails'`.

Then configure your `requirejs.yml` in config directory.

Comment: No I had tried that it still doesn't play nicely with rails 4.  It's also not being well maintained at the moment, I think the last commit it is over a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

This fork has included the rails 4 patches, try that one out. `https://github.com/scalient/requirejs-rails`

I am using it now, seems to work ok(as in no errors). Last step is a minified version of require.